# Creating Developer and production certificate issue?

Tags: ios, certificate

When I choose create certificate (developer or distribution) in my developer apple account in both certificate (developer or distribution) creations are invisible formate.

I attached screen shoot for your reference.
How can I solve this problem and create certificate.

[image: Certificate creation screen]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

See,you choose development only.Please choose production.

Comment: i am also choose production that also in same issue.

Comment: @Barani I guess you already have two distribution certificates. If you want to add another,you should delete one of them.

Comment: @Lumialxk- if i delete one certificate means in my uploaded application are affect or not.

Comment: @Barani No,it won't affect your apps.But you must use a new certificate when you update apps.

Comment: @Lumialxk- Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can only create 2 or 3 cer. So try it after deleting one of them.

Comment: if i delete one certificate means in my uploaded application are affect or not.

Comment: No it's not affected. So you can delete it